# using linq to find 2 values in a row

Tags: c#, linq

Is it easier to use linq to do the same thing as this code? (check and see how many values are equal to the value following):

```
int[] values = {1,2,3,3,5,6,7};

int counter=0;
for (int f =0; f< values.Length-1; f++)
{
  if(values[f]==values[f+1])
  {
   counter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the list supposed to wrap? What happens with number 7 for example? Do you compare to the first value (1) or just don't do anything?

Comment: yes, don't worry about the last value.

Comment: you need to check for `value.Length - 2` in your loop condition btw, or you'll fall off the end of the array and get an index out of bounds exception when you try to access `values[f+1]` the last time

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this quite easily with [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) in .NET 4:

```
var count = values.Zip(values.Skip(1), (x, y) => new { x, y })
                  .Count(pair => pair.x == pair.y);
```

The trick of combining `Zip` and `Skip(1)` takes a little bit of getting your head round, but it's a really neat one. Basically you start with a sequence of `n` values, and the result is a sequence of `n - 1` pairs, each of which contains a value and its successor.

From there, it's just a matter of counting the pairs which are the same :)

Note that the sequence in question will be evaluated twice, so you wouldn't want to do this for anything which was lazily evaluated, or which wouldn't give the same results when evaluated twice.

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think it's easier.  The code you have is easy to understand and concise, I wouldn't refactor it with linq.  Make sure you test it a bit more though, as you might get an out of bounds error on the last loop.

Comment: but in Linq how do you access the next value to compare it to the current value?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a very neat solution:

```
var list = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7 };
var pairs = SeqModule.Pairwise(list);
var count = pairs.Count(p => p.Item1 == p.Item2);
```

This requires that you reference the assembly `FSharp.Core` and you use `using Microsoft.FSharp.Collections;`. Alternatively, you can implement the `Pairwise` method as a extension method and thereby avoid using another assembly.

*For anyone who **might** be interested in F#, here is a solution:*

```
let lst = [1;2;3;3;5;6;7;7]
let count = lst |> Seq.pairwise
                |> Seq.filter (fun (x, y) -> x = y)
                |> Seq.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
var set = values.Where((value, i) => i < (values.Length - 1) ? values[i] == values[i + 1] : false);
```

EDIT:

Sorry, forgot to add set.Count() to get the result :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given that the values are in an array, you can do this:

```
int duplicates = values.Skip(1).Where((n, i) => n == values[i]).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could say something like:

```
private static int CountDoubles( IEnumerable<int> Xs )
{
  int?  prev  = null ;
  int   count = Xs.Count( curr => {
    bool isMatch = prev.HasValue && prev == curr ;
    prev = curr ;
    return isMatch ;
  } ) ;

  return count ;
}
```

but that's neither simpler nor cleaner than your original version. I'd tweak yours slightly, though::

```
public static int CountDoubles( int[] Xs )
{
  int n = 0 ;

  for ( int i = 1 ; i < Xs.Length ; ++i )
  {
    n += ( Xs[i-1] == Xs[i] ? 1 : 0 ) ;
  }

  return n ;
}
```